# Softlayer API to cancel various product immediately or on anniversary date

Tags: php, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have various use cases, want to know if it is possible for SoftLayer to

1. Create a cancellation request to cancel the device on the next anniversary day ?
2. Cancel the  next billing day cancellation request as in1
3. Create a new cancellation request to cancel the device immediately?

From my research on various SoftLayer APIs to cancel device:

1. Virtual Server
   SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest.deleteObject(), this method will cancel a instance effective immedately
   Is there another method that can cancell the both hourly and monthly virtual servers on the next anniversary date?
2. Baremetal Server

   - SoftLayer_Ticket.createCancelServerTicket()  cancel immediately , with four input parameters, 
     Will  monthly bare metal servers to be cancelled immediately?
   - SoftLayer_Ticket.createCancelServerTicket()  cancel on the anniversary day , with five input parameters,
3. Network, security, monitorying and storage:

   - SoftLayer_Billing_Item,  cancelService()  to cancel immediately
     Can All the above types of devices be cancelled immediately
   - cancelServiceOnAnniversaryDate() 
     Will all the above types of products be cancelled on anniversaryDate if use this this API call?

Comment: A related question is which SoftLayer API can use to cancel a device cancellation request ?

Answer (score 0):

All the devices and services in softlayer have associated a billing item, basically when you cancel a service or device you are cancelling the billing item.

so in regard your questions:

1.-Create a cancellation request to cancel the device on the next anniversary day ?
Resp.- Yes, it is possible you can use the methods [cancelItem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelItem) to cancel VSIs or Bare Metal servers, the method has a parameter called "cancelImmediately" when you set the value to false the device will be cancelled in the anniversary date. for services you can use [cancelServiceOnAnniversaryDate](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelServiceOnAnniversaryDate) method.

2.- Cancel the next billing day cancellation request as in1
Resp. It seems to me the same question as the fisrts one.

3.- Create a new cancellation request to cancel the device immediately?
Resp: yes, you can. You need to use the [cancelItem](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelItem) method or the [cancelService](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelService) method

Regarding to your research:
1.- yes the deleteObject() method will cancell the VSI inmediatly, if you wish to cancel the VSI in the aniversarydate use the cancelItem with the "cancelImmediately" set to false.

2.- This method I did not used a lot, but, if I am not wrong, it does not cancel the device automatically, your ticket must be reviewed for a Softlayer's employee and he cancels the server or VSI.

3.- yes all the types must be cancelled inmediatly with the cancelService() method.
  - Yes all the types must be cancelled in the anniversaryDate with the cancelServiceOnAnniversaryDate() method

For more information about billing items see this:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/node/274103

Comment: Nelson,Thank you for your response. For bare metal servers,

Comment: Thank you. If I use SoftLayer_Billing_Item::cancelItem (..,false,..)  to cancel on anniversary date, 

then I use SoftLayer_Billing_Item::voidCancelService() to try to cancel that previous cancellation request,
The API voidCancelService() has an error condition:
Error
SoftLayer_Exception_Public: Throw the exception "Cannot void cancellation for this service through the API." If a billing items service type cannot have a cancellation voided through the API.
Do you know what type of billing items service type cannot have a cancellation voided ?

Comment: I did not try to voids the cancelation, but it should creates an cancelation request, you can get that with this method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/getCancellationRequests, then try to void it using this method http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/void. I willl try to figure out more about this. But if you really need to void the cancelation try submitting a ticket to softlayer and ask them to void the cancellation.

Comment: Thank you.  I have to make  the API call in my application code to cancel the previous cancellation request, instead of submitting a softlayer ticket. It will be great if you can post finding when you have more information about billing_item_cancellationRequest_voide/services/

Comment: what kind of device did you cancel? I cancel a VSI and the voidCancelService() worked fine

Comment: I have an hourly virtual server SoftLayer_Billing_Item   $billingItem->cancelItem(false,false,"No longer needed","No longer needed, was testing server");   I can see this item is requested to be cancelled on Anniversary date, then called $clientHardwareItem->voidCancelService();   I got the error "There was an error querying the SoftLayer API: Unable to add ticket update,You cannot update a closed ticket."  Any idea of why I got that error  ?

Comment: well the error is pretty clear when you cancel an item, it creates a ticket, and it seems the ticket has been solved and closed (It means your cancellation has been processed), so when you call the voidCancelService it tries to update that ticket to void the cancellation, but it is not able to update it, because it has been closed.

Comment: The virtual hasn't been cancelled yet, It is scheduled to be cancelled on 6/1.  The previous call I uses is billing_item.cancelItem( false, false ...) which set to cancel on anniversary date, not immediate cancellation.  I tried to void the previous cancellation request using $clientHardwareItem->voidCancelService().   It gave me this ticket cannot be updated error.  How can I void the previous cancellation ?

Comment: if you are sure the ticket is not closed, it is an issue and you can submit an ticket to softlayer about that. In case the ticket has been closed the only way to void it is to submit a ticket to softlayer and ask them if they can cancel it.

Comment: I found after I call SoftLayer_Billing_Item $billingItem->cancelItem(false ...) , the billing object cancellationDate was set to $cancellationDate =>
  string(25) "2016-06-01T00:00:00-05:00"  (anniversary date),  a cancellation ticket was created then get approved and closed.  I then use  SoftLayer_Billing_Item $billingItem->voidCancelService() try to void the previous cancellation request.  I noticed the $billingItem object 's cancellationDate value got removed after the voidCancelService() call, even if I got the ticket closed error.

Comment: So the billingItem object cancellationDate value changed to null after the voidCancelService(), even there's an exception.  Does it mean previous cancellation has already been called ?  Is there anyway to use API to void cancellation for the previous approved cancellation, instead of manually submit a SoftLayer ticket ?

Comment: Interesting thing is,  I executed another API call $clientHardwareItem->cancelService();  on the same hourly virtual server where got exception withthe voidCancelServer() call. I found there's another ticket created for immediate cancellation of the device. And the new ticket said the device has been reclaimed.  Will the new SoftLayer cancellation ticket always overwrites the old ticket on the same device ?

Comment: It seems that the voidCancelService() method worked the first time that you called it (despite the error), by rule a closed ticket cannot be updated, so the behavior you saw is strange. When you called the cancelService() method the billingItem (whose cancellation request was removed due the call to voidCancelService method)  was set to cancel again and a cancellation ticket was created again. that happened because the cancellation was voided. If the billing was already set to be cancelled and you try to cancel it again (using cancelItem ot cancelService) you will get an error.

Comment: so it looks to me if voidCancelService() method worked the first time , it should not generate that ticket error, or if there's ticket error then the method should not remove the original value of cancellationDate on the billingItem which then allows another cancelServer() call ?

Comment: It is error in the ticket, an closed ticket cannot be update, but the cancellation was voided.