# Softlayer api: The methods of destory vm(cancle instance) with different pay-mode

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

As we know that sl support hourly and monthly pay-mode for ordering a vm.

**[Q1]:**For a hourly pay-mode vm,  I can use guest.deleteObject(id=instance_id) to Cancel an instance immediately. But the website has the note: 
[image]

Does it means that hourly vm can NOT be destoried  immediately at the latest day of a month?

**[Q2]:**For a monthly pay-mode vm, the website page offer user two ways to destroy it. As shown in flowing pic:
[image]
Could you tell me which sl api can help to Cancel an instance by 'Anniversary Date' ?
How can I get the vm state of which the vm has already submit the query of Cancel some instances by 'Anniversary Date' or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hourly VSI cannot be canceled immediately starting on the first second on the anniversary date. Since your billing date is on 2016-11-01 it means that is possible to cancel the item on 2016-10-30 until 11:59 PM

Regarding the cancellation on Anniversary date, here's a good answer on that matter: [Softlayer API to cancel various product immediately or on anniversary date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348287/softlayer-api-to-cancel-various-product-immediately-or-on-anniversary-date)

Comment: Thanks for your help. With the help of ref(Softlayer API to cancel various product immediately or on anniversary date), I can cancel the VSI on anniversary date by using billing_item.cancelItem.  But another question is, if offered a instance id, how can I know this VSI has already submit the request cancel on anniversary  or not ?

Comment: If I call cancelItem for a VSI which has already submit the same request before, it will raise SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): This cancellation could not be processed. Please contact support. This billing item is already canceled.  So I need a api to check first, could you help me?

Comment: I have tried getPendingCancellationFlag(id=bill_item_id), but the return value is empty string.

Comment: Another questions about the params of calcelItem().                                    Q1: It has a param named cancelAssociatedBillingItems, could you offer me some material about AssociatedBillingItems, some examples will be better~.                                                                                       Q2 : And does cancelServiceOnAnniversaryDate() will cancel AssociatedBillingItems ?

Comment: "deleteObject() method will cancell the VSI inmediatly, if you wish to cancel the VSI in the aniversarydate use the cancelItem with the "cancelImmediately" set to false" " -----  For the params cancel_associated_billing_items of cancelItem(),  does it mean that deleteObject(id) operation equals to cancelItem(cancel_immediately=True,cancel_associated_billing_items=True,  reason='',customer_note='',id=bill_item_id).  cancel_associated_billing_items is set as True, is it right?            Looking forward to your reply.